# Why isn't the state of Root component changing?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

This is my Root Component, it passes an array of url details in initial state to tab_list which renders individual tab_item for each url. I am also passing a function to delete the url , but when I do that and make changes to state , the state is not affected by it. :

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import TabList from './tab_list.js';

export default class Root extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        tabs: this.props.tabs
    };
  };

  removeURL(key) {
    console.log("This is the Key " , key);
    chrome.storage.local.get({urls: []}, function (result) {
      var urls = result.urls;
      urls = urls.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.id != key;
      });
      this.state = {
        tabs: urls
      };
      chrome.storage.local.set({urls: urls}, function () {});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <TabList tabs={this.state.tabs} remove_url={this.removeURL.bind(this)}/> 
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my tab_list component -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import TabItem from './tab_item';

export default class TabList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.props.tabs.map(function(tab, i) {
          return <TabItem url={tab.url} url_id={tab.id} key={i} id={i} remove_url={this.props.remove_url}/>;
        }.bind(this))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my tab_item component -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class TabItem extends Component {
  render() {
    var self = this;
    return (
        <div> 
            <li>{this.props.url}</li> <img src="img/ic_clear_black_24dp_1x.png" onClick={() => self.onClick(this.props)}/>
        </div>
    );
  }

  onClick(props) {
    this.props.remove_url(this.props.url_id);
  }

}
```

Comment: are your state not updating or the children components are not getting the change ?

Comment: Well the change is not affected in my UI. Everything is working fine, when I click on cross image for a specific url, it is getting deleted in my chrome storage but it is not getting removed from my UI.

Comment: you can check at Tablist with a componentWillReceiveProps(nextPorps) to check if the changins states are there in Tablist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call setState in your storage callback

```
chrome.storage.local.get({urls: []}, function (result) {
      var urls = result.urls;
      urls = urls.filter(function(obj) {
        return obj.id != key;
      });
      this.setState({
        tabs: urls
      });
      chrome.storage.local.set({urls: urls}, function () {});
    }.bind(this));
```

Comment: Still not working. It is giving error this.setState is not a function

Comment: Updated, forgot to bind (assumed you were using es6)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Comment: No worries. Good luck