# Component renders nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just started to learn React. I want to use my already built REST api but I've encountered a problem while I was trying to get an **user** element from my api.

I have a **UserServices** class that has two axios methods in it, **getUserById** and **getAllUsers**.

```
public static getUserById(id: number): Promise<IUser> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        axios.get(this.root + id).then((response: any) => {
            let character = this.toUser(response.data);
            resolve(character);
        },
            (error: any) => {
                reject(error);
            });
    });
}
```

[image]

My problem is when I try to render my **user**, because I get nothing.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  user: IUser;
  render() {
    UsersService.getUserById(2).then(res => this.user = res);

    return (
        <div className="app">
          <User user = {this.user} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my user component

```
export interface UserProps {
    user: IUser;
}

interface UserState {
    myUser: IUser;
}

export class User extends React.Component<UserProps, UserState> {

    public static defaultProps: UserProps = {
        user: {
            name: ''
        }
    }

    constructor(props: UserProps) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            myUser: props.user
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <span>{this.state.myUser.name}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.user` will still be `undefined` when you return the div containing it in `App#render`. See the linked dupetarget for why. The promise is resolved **later**. You should be 1. Retrieving the user earlier, 2. Showing a "loading" message while the user is being loaded, and 3. Using `setState` within the `then` callback to change the state when you have the user (which will cause a new rendering).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @FrankerZ: Yes, it is. Have a read. Couldn't be much more clearly trying to use an asynchronous result prior to it arriving.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This is a fault of the state not being reread again to trigger a re-render. While that answer mentions the asynchronous nature of the render method just returning, I think this question is more directly related to why the app isn't re-rendered when the user is then resolved.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it is not related to the question you marked as dup

Comment: @Cleiton: Again: It couldn't be more clearly trying to use an asynchronous result prior to it arriving. This is the canonical dupe for that situation.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder A cannocal dupe would be `this.state.user = UsersService.getUserById(2)` or similar. I've nominated the question for reopening, as I feel this is more related to react/rendering.

Comment: But I think it is more a React related question, as the user should know how to deal with async code in a opinionated way.

Comment: @Cleiton: So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221697/how-to-re-render-reactjs-component-after-update-in-data) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39188002/why-isnt-the-state-of-root-component-changing) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36183304/change-component-state-on-button-click/36184039#36184039)? I've added the one that seems like the dupetarget for the other two.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder all are dups, but the last one has the best answer of all.

Comment: @Cleiton: Yeah, agreed. I wish it were the earlier one, but you're right it's got the clearly better answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anything variable, you either need to use state management, so that react can detect a change to `this.state.user`, and rerendering the appropriate components.

EDIT: As Cleiton mentioned, [`componentDidMount()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) would be a better place to put the call.

Set your state as well, so that your app will rerender when state changes. In either component be sure to check if User is null, and display some type of loading in the render method, or return null (To render nothing) in the case of the user hasn't been loaded yet.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
      super();

      this.state = {
          user: null
      }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    UsersService.getUserById(2).then(res => this.setState({user: res}));
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <div className="app">
          <User user={this.state.user} />
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `render` method should be pure, you should not be doing anything remotely related to modifying any component's state within a render function. Tell him to use `componentDidMount` instead.

Comment: `User` will throw an exception with the above unless you also modify `User` (or modify the `render` above not to use `User` when `this.state.user` is `null`).